# How can I access the csproj file via a T4 text template in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, t4

How can I access the csproj file via a T4 text template in Visual Studio 2008?

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
using(StreamReader assemblyInfoReader = File.OpenText(Host.ResolvePath("ProjectName.csproj")))
{
 ...
}
```

The error message I get is "Unable to locate file".

When I type the absolute path the message I get is "The length cannot be zero".

When I try to open a different file such as AssemblyInfo.cs it works fine.

As an aside, I am trying to access the ApplicationVersion tag from within the csproj file. This is different from what is returned from:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Comment: Are you trying to edit the project file of the currently opened project?

Comment: No, I am not trying to edit the file. I am just trying to read the file.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it doesn't work because it is an open file but I thought I would ask anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method for getting the .csproj path...

```
string csprojPath = Host.TemplateFile.Replace(Path.GetFileName(Host.TemplateFile), "ProjectName.csproj");
```

'Host.Templatefile' gets the path for the 'TemplateFileName.tt'

This is assuming that the .TT file is in the same folder as your .csproj